# How to send Ajax request to multiple model class with data parameter?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, c#-3.0

I am trying to send Ajax request to a controller action that takes a class as parameter that contains multiple models. I have figured the way to send the request to one specific model from multiple models. But the problem that I am facing is how to bind parameters for the target model.

Request:

```
    function EditModalOnComplete() {
        var modelData = { Data: "euro", Type: null, PosNumber: 0, OrderNumber: 0, ServerName: 
        "serverDefualted" }
        var modelName = { "orderModel":modelData}
       $.ajax({
           url: '@Url.Action("SearchResult", "Orders")',
           data:modelName ,
           success: function (){
       },
       error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
              alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Controller Action:

```
   public ActionResult SearchResult(BindedModels models)
    {
 //Code 
return View();
    }
```

Combined Models Class

```
public class BindedModels 
{
    public OrderModel orderModel{ get; set; }
    public DetailsModel details{ get; set; }
}
```

Model Class:

```
   public class orderModel
    {
        public string  Data{ get; set; }
        public int? Type{ get; set; }
        public int? PosNumber{ get; set; }
        public int? OrderNumber{ get; set; }
        public string ServerName { get; set; }

    }
```

I would like to send modelData along side with the request to the model that is called orderModel and supply those data to it. How can I do this. I do get the model when I inspect the code but its data is null.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue may be that you need to stringify your model.

Replace this in your Ajax call:

```
data:model,
```

With this:

```
data: JSON.stringify(model),
```

I assume you have a typo in your code sample since you use `modelName` when creating the JS object but pass `model` in the actual call, unless that is the reason why it's not working, which may very well be the case.

I also just noticed you are missing the request type as well as the content type:

```
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json"
```

So to put it all together:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       contentType: "application/json",
       url: '@Url.Action("SearchResult", "Orders")',
       data:JSON.stringify(modelName),
       success: function (){
   },
   error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
          alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

And make sure to mark your controller's action with the `[HttpPost]` attribute:

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult SearchResult(BindedModels models)
```

Comment: I have tried the solution that you provided but now I am getting the model as null?

Comment: Yes You are correct but this typo was when creating the post in my code its fine

Comment: @moe1792 I just noticed you are missing the request type as well: `type: "POST",`

Comment: Yes That's correct and thanks for your replay but I do get the request when I place a break point I get an object for the orderModel but its properties are null. So if that would be the cause I will be surprised but I will give it a go. By the way the data I am sending is not a JSON but I am sending the model instead

Comment: Sorry but that is not the cause I have tried your solutions with all recommendation

Comment: @moe1792 If all else fails, check your casing as model binding is cAsE sEnSiTiVe.

Comment: @moe1792 also, try adding [FromBody] on your controller and also [HttpPost] like below:
[HttpPost]
  public ActionResult SearchResult([FromBody]BindedModels models)

Comment: sometimes the data from models come as null if they are not properly casted to the right data type, happened to me multiple times, trying to get an int value from a input and not casting it to int before sending to controller, might as well check that

Comment: Yes I do get the model but its properties are empty so I have considered Case Sensitive

Comment: @moe1792 I think it would be helpful if you post a snapshot of the object in the debugger so we can see what is and what is NOT being populated.

Answer (score 0):

Fix ajax:

```
function EditModalOnComplete() {

        var modelData ={ orderModel: { Data: "euro", Type: null, PosNumber: 0, 
OrderNumber: 0, ServerName: "serverDefualted" }, details: {} };
        
       $.ajax({
           url:  "/Orders/SearchResult",
           data:modelData ,
           success: function (){
       },
       error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
              alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", contentType: "application/json", url: '@Url.Action("SearchResult", "Orders")', data:modelName, cache:false, success: function (){ }, error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ alert(xhr.responseText); } });
```

Answer (score 0):

/* The issue is with the cache */

function EditModalOnComplete() {

```
    var modelData ={ orderModel: { Data: "euro", Type: null, PosNumber: 0,
```

OrderNumber: 0, ServerName: "serverDefualted" }, details: {} };

```
   $.ajax({
       url:  "/Orders/SearchResult",
       data:modelData ,
       cache: false,
       success: function (){
   },
   error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
          alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```